# Terminology regarding divisor on a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, divisors

Suppose that $D = \sum n_i P_i$ is a divisor on a curve $C$, say, over a field. Is there a standard algebraic geometry terminology referring to the set $\{ P_i : n_i \neq 0 \} \subset |C|$? Support of $D$? Locus of $D$?

Comment: The "support of $D$" sounds good to me.

Comment: ...and it is used in EGA, Hartshorne, ...